# Razor Pages with Services and Repositories

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to understand how to separate concerns in my application and I have used Repository pattern before,

Problem is that i don't understand where the service comes in.

Let's say i have a simple CreateModel

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository _genereicRepository;

    public CreateModel(IGenericRepository genericRepository)
    {
        _genereicRepository = genericRepository;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Entity Entity { get;set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        var entities = _genericRepository.GetEntities();
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        _genereicRepository.AddEntity(Entity);
        _genereicRepository.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and the rest is up to the repository to do the database calls.

Now why would i need a service in here and what would it exactly handle or abastract even more since there is nothing else to abstract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not need services, it all depends on how complex your system is. If all your controller methods do is done with one object and one repository call, I wouldn't add a service.

I add services when the operations the controllers want to perform are getting too complicated to keep them in the controller. For instance, if one controller method updates multiple objects and requires some logic (sometimes this group of objects is updated, sometimes that group) - I put that logic in a service.

Comment: So you are telling me if there are a lot of logic when it involves more than one object i should make a service, and on that service i DI the repository for DA calls?

Comment: Deciding when to add a service is a judgement called. "When a controller method involves more than one object" can be a good rule of thumb for now. Yes, inject the service to the controller and the repository to the service.

Comment: I get it now, I do have a lot of logic in some pages that involve multiple objects, hence why i found it hard to get by and wanted to implement repository pattern but that wasn't enough when started mixing different repositories and some added logic, now that makes sense.